# command line to determine which Ethernet interface is in use

Tags: batch-file, cmd, netsh, ipconfig

I have a script that I wrote to help to configure computers after they are deployed. The script does things like sets computer name, enable's BitLocker, etc. The one thing that I am struggling with is the setting of an IP address. The computers that I am using (servers to be specific) have 4 NIC ports and they are named Local area connection and Local area connection 2-4. The problem is that the technicians that deploy these servers don't always plug into the same port, and additionally the deployment image doesn't always assign the ethernet net local area connection to the NIC port 1.

Here is a copy of the script that I have, which works perfectly if only a single NIC port is enabled.  What I need to do is pipe the output of the Local Area Connection name that has an IP address (because DHCP already exists) into a variable that I can put into my `netsh` command.

Current code in place

```
:IPADDRESS
@echo Would you like static or DHCP?
@echo press 1 for static
@echo press 2 for dhcp
Choice /C:12 /N /M "?:"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO IPDHCP
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO IPSTATIC

:IPSTATIC
set /P _IPADDR=Please enter IP address:
set /p _Subnet=Please enter Subnet:
set /p _DefaultGateway=Please Enter Default Gateway:

netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection 2" static %_IPADDR% %_Subnet% %_DefaultGateway%
goto START

:IPDHCP
  netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection 2" dhcp
 goto START

 :disipaddr
  netsh interface ip show config name="Local Area Connection 2"
```

The name "Local Area Connection 2" is the part that changes from build to build. So that is the part that I need to isolate. I am fairly certain that the for `/p` and using it against either `ipconfig /all` or netsh  interface ip show config would be the correct way to go.

Thank you in advance for all of the help.

Answer (score 1):

This will work and tested on Windows 7.

### A batch.bat file:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%F in ('wmic nic where "NetConnectionStatus=2 and AdapterTypeId=0" get  NetConnectionID /format:list') do set interfaceName=%%F

echo Your Interface is %interfaceName%

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use `wmic` for that? Something along the lines of:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %F in ('wmic nic where "NetConnectionStatus=2 and AdapterTypeId=0" get  NetConnectionID /format:list') do set %activeNet%=%F
```

It should return all connected (`NetConnectionStatus=2`) Eth/802.3 (`AdapterTypeID=0` ) interfaces - ie the one connected in your instance. *(for some reason it also reports WiFi as 802.3 on my XP laptop, but this should not be a problem for a server)*

You can try it directly from command line as it is to see if it returns what it's supposed to. Replace `%F` with `%%F` if used in batch.

Please note it may be necessary to check the value returned for connected interface as it differs for various OSes. [Full description of the Win32_NetworkAdapter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (whic `nic` is an alias for)

If you're 100% sure you want to check only ones starting with "Local Area Connection" you could use `where "netconnectionID like 'Local Area Connection%'"` instead (or combine it with other conditions)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean connected, which are in use?

```
:_InterfaceConnected_
FOR /F "tokens=3,*" %%A IN ('netsh interface show interface^|find "Connected"') DO (
echo %%B
echo connected : %%B
)
@echo:

:_InterfaceDisconnected_
FOR /F "tokens=3,*" %%A IN ('netsh interface show interface^|find "Disconnected"') DO (
echo %%B
echo disconnected : %%B
)
```

gives as output :

```
Ethernet
connected : Ethernet

Ethernet 3
disconnected : Ethernet 3
```

The complete overview, via command

```
> netsh interface show interface
```

output :

```
Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled        Disconnected   Dedicated        Ethernet 3
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Ethernet
```