# A batch for finding the IP address of the connected interfaces

Tags: batch-file, quotes, wmic, netsh

Long time reading. First time poster.

I have a Windows machine with many NICs, and rather than the normal ipconfig, I want a simple way of showing the IP address(es) of just the adapter(s) that is(are) connected.

Looking at [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595499/command-line-to-determine-which-ethernet-interface-is-in-use) on this forum, I think the following command would work, if somebody please point me on how to pass the double quotes to the last variable:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %F in ('wmic nic where "NetConnectionStatus=2 and AdapterTypeId=0" get  NetConnectionID /format:list') do netsh interface ip show config name="%F%"
```

Note: in a batch file, it would be %%F instead of %F.

I've tried several escaping methods, but it seems the part after the %F is not recognized.

The expected output would it be something like (please ignore the Spanish, the IP address is the information of interest):

```
netsh interface ipv4 show config name="Wi-Fi"

Configuración para la interfaz "Wi-Fi"
    DHCP habilitado:                         Sí
    Dirección IP:                           192.168.1.12
```

Comment: Why have you used an undefined variable named `F` here `"%F%"`" instead of the result, `"%F"`?

Comment: I did try the "%F", but it didn't work either. So I see the %F% like trying to pass an echo of the previous output to the variable. And the "name" filed requires the network adapter in double quotes.

Comment: I can't remember the reason why but I am sure there is an explanation here or on the DosTips forums, but using a second `FOR` command to parse the output fixes the issue you are having.  So to fix your original code to run from the command line would be: `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %F in ('wmic nic where "NetConnectionStatus=2 and AdapterTypeId=0" get  NetConnectionID /format:list^|find /i "netconnectionid"') do @for /f "delims=" %G IN ("%~F") do netsh interface ip show config name="%G"`

Comment: in short words, the reason (@Squashman's comment above) is an additional `CR` at the end of each `wmic` output line, which is ignored/removed by the second `for` loop. (There is no interface named `Wi-Fi<CR>`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using the two Powershell cmdlets `Get-NetAdapter` and `Get-NetIPAddress` with a batch file :

```bash
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM Get the list of network interfaces
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('powershell -Command "Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object { $_.Status -eq 'Up' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name"') do (
    set interface=%%a
    REM Get the IP address for the current interface
    for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('powershell -Command "Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias '%%a'| Where-Object { $_.AddressFamily -eq 'IPv4' -and $_.PrefixOrigin -eq 'Dhcp' -and $_.AddressState -eq 'Preferred' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress"') do (
        set ip=%%b
        REM Check if the IP address is not empty
        if not "!ip!"=="" (
            echo Interface: !interface!
            echo IP Address: !ip!
            echo.
        )
    )
)
endlocal
pause
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to continue to use WMIC with NetSh, then the following may suit your purposes:

Directly in cmd.exe:

```bash
For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe /NameSpace:\\Root\StandardCimv2 Path MSFT_NetConnectionProfile Get InterfaceAlias /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do @For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=:" %H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe Interface IPv4 Show Config Name^="%G" 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "IP"') Do @For /F %I In ("%H") Do @Echo %I
```

In a batch file:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
 /NameSpace:\\Root\StandardCimv2 Path MSFT_NetConnectionProfile Get
 InterfaceAlias /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=:" %%H In ('
 %SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe Interface IPv4 Show Config Name^="%%G" 2^>NUL
 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "IP"') Do For /F %%I In ("%%H") Do Echo %%I

Pause

EndLocal
```

*Please note that this assumes that the string `IP` is unique in the output for the target line, (it clearly is for both English and your language, but that is not a guarantee).*

---

For the reason given in the footnote for the above code examples, my preference would be to just use WMIC, like this:

Directly in cmd.exe:

```bash
For /F Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe NIC Where "Not NetConnectionStatus Is Null" Assoc /AssocClass:Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration 2^>NUL') Do @For /F Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe NICConfig Where Index^=%G Get IPAddress') Do @Echo %H
```

In a batch file:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

For /F Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe NIC
 Where "Not NetConnectionStatus Is Null" Assoc
 /AssocClass:Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration 2^>NUL'
) Do For /F Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %%H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
 NICConfig Where Index^=%%G Get IPAddress') Do Echo %%H

Pause

EndLocal
```

---

I suppose you could also get the help of PowerShell too…

Directly in cmd.exe:

```bash
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias $(Get-NetConnectionProfile -IPv4Connectivity 'Subnet','LocalNetwork','Internet' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).InterfaceAlias | Select-Object InterfaceAlias, IPAddress"
```

As a batch file:

```bash
@Echo Off

%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command^
 "Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias "^
 "$(Get-NetConnectionProfile -IPv4Connectivity 'Subnet','LocalNetwork',"^
 "'Internet' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).InterfaceAlias | Select-Object "^
 "InterfaceAlias, IPAddress"

Pause
```

---

*Please note the above examples are untested.*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, as the first show the real connected adapter whereas the second includes the logically connected adapters. However, because at one given time time I can have more than one interface connected (as a matter of fact considering the logical adapters), I would like to see its name followed by the IP (I don't care whether additional information kinda ipconfig is shown), so I will have a look on your code for ideas on how to do that. And I'm not specifically tied to WMIC, whatever other code that find the connected interface(s) would work for me.

Comment: @Feliciano, your question never mentioned the name, it stated 'a simple way of showing the IP address(es)', (and in fact it showed part output from a command, without isolating either the name or  the IP Address). In the first examples above, you could change the `Echo` to `%G = %I` or `%%G = %%I` respectively. In the second examples, if you wanted only the connected ones, change `"Not NetConnectionStatus Is Null"` to `"NetConnectionStatus='2'"`.